# Reasons for and debugging a contract that failed when deploying into blockchain

Tags: contract-deployment, remix, solc

I have a program that has been tested from remix's VM, and compiled with solc, in both cases without any failure.

However, when I try to use a custom script for deploying it into the rinkeby testnet (MIT-licensed script for deploying with works as I have succesfully deployed other contracts before), the tx ends up failing:

https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0x2794f7da8422e086d1ff22ececed2c971c869ae8729efedf562ca5b0e1576b23

What are the reasons for a tx to fail? is there any way of debugging it or figuring out the problem?

Comment: It is odd, the constructor appears to run without problem, but the gas was used fully. Check increasing the gas, perhasp 1M is too low.